# Does turning iMessage off remove previous iMessages and text messages?

Tags: messages

Does turning iMessage off remove previous iMessages and text messages that were saved on the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Your messages are tied to the device specifically, not necessarily the account.

If you wanted to delete the messages, you could delete whole conversations by swiping left in the messages list or individually deleting messages by double tapping on the message.